# `express.static` not working inside `express-promise-router`

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I'm trying to refactor certain static route in my express app.

First, if i do following inside `index.ts`, **it will works just fine**:

```
import * as express from 'express';
const app = express();
app.use('/something', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'something')));
```

However i want to make my code more tidy, so i need to refactor into separate route handler files, i.e. i create `route/something.ts` for handling route to `/something`.
So i did following:

Inside `index.ts`, it become:

```
import * as express from 'express';
const app = express();
app.use('/something', require('./route/something.ts);
```

and inside `./route/something.ts`:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import PromiseRouter from 'express-promise-router';
const router = PromiseRouter();
router.route('/')
                .get(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../', 'something')));
module.exports = router;
```

notice that i already change the dir structure from `../` to `../..` but somehow it still doesn't work when trying to hit api endpoint `localhost:3000/something/static.jpg` it returns error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot GET /something/static.jpg</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

why is this happening? how to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This line (in `route/something.ts`):

```js
router.route('/')
                .get(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../', 'something')));
```

Should be changed to:

```js
router.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../', 'something')));
```

You also don't need to use `express-promise-router`, you can just create the router using `const router = express.Router()`.

See the [routing docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) for more info on this.

Comment: what if i want to use `express-promise-router` how to work around that? since i already implement hundreds endpoints using that library, just for the sake of consistency

Comment: @xcode You can keep on using it, the fix I've suggested above should still work.

Comment: what i mean is that how to use `express.static` inside `router = Promiserouter()` instead of using `router = express.Router()`

Comment: @xcode You can use `express.static(...)` with a `PromiseRouter` the same way you use an Express router (`express.Router`). See [the `express-promise-router` documentation](https://github.com/express-promise-router/express-promise-router) for more info on this.